# How to show Variants record from tables in a specific manner?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I have 5 tables of variants, details below:

Product Table:

```
ProductID Name
    12    T-Shirt
```

Variant Table:

```
VariantID  ProductID  Name
    1         12      Size
    2         12      Color
    3         12      Material
```

VariantOption Table:

```
VariantOptionID  VariantID  VariantOptionName
      1              1            Small
      2              1            Medium
      3              2            Red
      4              2            Blue
      5              3            Cotton
      6              3            Lawn
```

Sku Table:

```
SkuID  ProductID  SKU              Price   Barcode
  1       12      Th-Sm-Red-Cot    120.00  345423
  2       12      Th-Sm-Red-Lon    130.00  345454
  3       12      Th-Sm-Blue-Cot   140.00  345451
  4       12      Th-Sm-Blue-Lon   150.00  345431
  5       12      Th-Md-Red-Cot    160.00  345472
  6       12      Th-Md-Red-Lon    170.00  345479
  7       12      Th-Md-Blue-Cot   180.00  654353
  8       12      Th-Md-Blue-Lon   190.00  254353
```

VariantOptionCombination Table:

```
VariantOptionID  SkuID
      1            1
      3            1
      5            1
      1            2
      3            2
      6            2
      1            3
      4            3
      5            3
      1            4
      4            4
      6            4
```

I want to show these tables records in web page.
Please guide me how can I achieve to retrieve record in this manner:

```
Size    Color  Material  Price   Sku
Small   Red    Cotton    120.00  345423
Small   Red    Lawn      130.00  345454
Small   Blue   Cotton    140.00  345451
Small   Blue   Lawn      150.00  345431
Medium  Red    Cotton    160.00  345472
Medium  Red    Lawn      170.00  345479
Medium  Blue   Cotton    180.00  654353
Medium  Blue   Lawn      190.00  254353
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I am using Sql server.

Comment: I guess you have tried something already. Can you post your SQL so that we can help to correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` and `pivot` to achieve your desired result.

```
select Material,Color,Size,Price, barcode from
(
select v.Name, vo.VariantOptionName,  s.barcode, s.Price
from sku s
join VariantOptionCombination voc
on s.SkuID = voc.SkuID
join VariantOption vo
on vo.VariantOptionID = voc.VariantOptionID  
join Variant v
on v.VariantID = vo.VariantID
) as t1
pivot
(   max(VariantOptionName) 
    for Name in ( Size, Color, Material)
)  as t2;
```

The idea here is to consider `sku` as main table and use `join` to get `VariantOptionName` from table `VariantOption` and `Name` from table `Variant` Table first and then using `pivot` on `Name` to transform rows to columns.

**Result:**

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| Material | Color  |  Size  | Price  | barcode |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| Cotton   | Red    | Small  | 120,00 |  345423 |
| Lawn     | Blue   | Small  | 150,00 |  345431 |
| Cotton   | Blue   | Small  | 140,00 |  345451 |
| Lawn     | Red    | Small  | 130,00 |  345454 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

**[Pivot DEMO](http://rextester.com/JDMTG61425)**

---

**Update:**

If you do not want to use `pivot`, you can use conditional aggregation.

```
select  max(case when v.Name = 'Size' then vo.VariantOptionName end) as Size,
        max(case when v.Name = 'Color' then vo.VariantOptionName end) as Color,
        max(case when v.Name = 'Material' then vo.VariantOptionName end) as Material,
        s.price,
        s.barcode      
from sku s
join VariantOptionCombination voc
on s.SkuID = voc.SkuID
join VariantOption vo
on vo.VariantOptionID = voc.VariantOptionID  
join Variant v
on v.VariantID = vo.VariantID
group by s.barcode, s.Price;
```

**[Aggregation DEMO](http://rextester.com/YSF86728)**

Comment: Can i achieve the same without using pivot?

Comment: @Ahmed: Yes, you can. Kindly check the updated answer.

Comment: Whats your opinion is my database design is right? Or i can improve this?

Comment: @Ahmad: Design seems ok. However you can ask another question regarding current design. I hope someone will look into it in detail :-)

Comment: Thanks Zarruq for the help.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Yes i accept the answer. Sorry for the delay i am new to stack Overflow.